# Pandas - group by to return first occurence and there on every third occurence of a value

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to filter records from a Dataframe based on their occurence. I am trying to filter out the `first occurence` and then on `every third occurence` based on emp_id. Given below is how my Dataframe is.

```
emp_id,date,value
101,2018-12-01,10001
101,2018-12-03,10002
101,2018-12-05,10003
101,2018-12-13,10004
```

In the above sample, expected output is :

```
emp_id,date,value
101,2018-12-01,10001
101,2018-12-13,10004
```

Given below is the code I have built this far:

```
df['emp_id'] = df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount()+1
df['emp_id'] = np.where((df['emp_id']%3)==0,1,0)
```

This however returns back `2nd occurence` and `every third occurrence` after that. How could I modify such that it returns back the `first occurence` and then on `every third occurence` based on emp_id

Comment: Are you looking for `df['emp_id'] = df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount()+1; df[df.emp_id % 3 == 1]`?

Comment: @coldspeed, trying to return the very first occurrence and 3rd occurrence post that by emp_id

Comment: Doesn't the code in my comment do that? Help me understand how it is different please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with check `0` or `1`, assign to column is not necessary, is possible create helper `Series` s:

```
print (df)
   emp_id        date  value
0     101  2018-12-01  10001
1     101  2018-12-03  10002
2     101  2018-12-05  10003
3     101  2018-12-13  10004
4     101  2018-12-01  10005
5     101  2018-12-03  10006
6     101  2018-12-05  10007
7     101  2018-12-13  10008

s = df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount()
df['check'] = (s % 3) == 0
```

Alternative:

```
s = df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount()  + 1
df['check'] = (s % 3) == 1
```

---

```
print (df)
   emp_id        date  value  check
0     101  2018-12-01  10001   True
1     101  2018-12-03  10002  False
2     101  2018-12-05  10003  False
3     101  2018-12-13  10004   True
4     101  2018-12-01  10005  False
5     101  2018-12-03  10006  False
6     101  2018-12-05  10007   True
7     101  2018-12-13  10008  False
```

Comment: df = df[(s % 3) == 0] filters every third record but misses the first occurence..

Comment: @darkhorse - Do you add `1` in `df.groupby('emp_id').cumcount() + 1` or not ?

Comment: it returns True for the third record but however the first recorded is not captured :(, tried both the method as suggested

Comment: @darkhorse - Maybe groups are not sorted? how working first `df = df.sort_values('emp_id')` and then apply solution ?